# wildfly 8.0 jdk 1.7 error deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly-8

i have a war , and import in eclipse kepler, but i have this error.
 and i dont know what happened.

I use server wildfly 8.0 with jdk 1.7.

```
16:46:39,244 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) java.lang.NullPointerException
16:46:39,244 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at Cupon.Estudiante.getValidarEntrada(Estudiante.java:99)
16:46:39,244 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.jsp.loginCosmosFinanciera_jsp._jspService(loginCosmosFinanciera_jsp.java:88)
16:46:39,245 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
16:46:39,245 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
16:46:39,245 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366)
16:46:39,245 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
16:46:39,245 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
16:46:39,246 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
16:46:39,246 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)   
16:46:39,246 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
16:46:39,246 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
16:46:39,246 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
16:46:39,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
16:46:39,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
16:46:39,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52)
16:46:39,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
16:46:39,247 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
16:46:39,248 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
16:46:39,248 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
16:46:39,248 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
16:46:39,248 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
16:46:39,249 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
16:46:39,249 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
16:46:39,249 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
16:46:39,249 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
16:46:39,249 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
16:46:39,250 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
16:46:39,250 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168)
16:46:39,250 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687)
16:46:39,250 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
16:46:39,250 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
16:46:39,251 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

thx for help
Ps: Before it´s run in jboss 5.10 in eclipse juno, and here works fine.

Comment: Have a look in Estudiante.java line 99 to see what variable is null

Comment: Please provide the code of your `Estudiante` class.

Comment: thx for help, i resolved my problem, is that problem with databases